# How can I attach to docker container running in detached mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

If I start up a docker container in detached mode using the command:

```
docker run -d ubuntu
```

the container immediately exits. `docker ps -a` yields the output (selected columns shown):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             STATUS
245fe871a1e3        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         Exited (0) 4 minutes ago
```

Is it possible to start the same container (container ID `245fe871a1e3`) in interactive mode with a terminal session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no such a way to archive this. `docker attach` and `docker exec` are working against running container only, but if you `docker start` the container in your case, it'll exited immediately again because the `CMD` is `/bin/bash`.

There's also [a discussion](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter/issues/27) about this, post some key info here:

> It's not possible to enter a stopped container, because the processes are gone, and therefore, the namespaces are gone as well.