# Docker Container is not running

Tags: docker, deployment

Please help. When I want to go into a container is says

Error response from daemon: Container 90599013c666d332ff6560ccde5053d9127e72042ecc3887550aef90fa1d1eac is not running

My DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Anton Lapitski <a.lapitski@godeltech.com>

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app


ADD ./ /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/src/app/entry.sh"]
```

Starting script - start.sh:

```
sudo docker build -t starter .
sudo docker run -t -v mounted-directory:/usr/src/app/mounted-directory -p 80:80 starter
```

entry.sh script:

```
echo "Hello World"
ls -l
pwd
if mountpoint -q /mounted-directory 
then
  echo "mounted"
else
  echo "not mounted"
fi
```

sudo docker ps -a gives:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE  COMMAND CREATED STATUS   PORTS   NAMES
90599013c666   starter "/bin/sh -c /usr/src…"   18 minutes ago      Exited (0) 18 minutes ago                       thirsty_wiles
```

And mosе important:

```
sudo docker exec -it 90599013c666 bash
Error response from daemon: Container 90599013c666d332ff6560ccde5053d9127e72042ecc3887550aef90fa1d1eac is not running
```

Please could you tell what I am doing wrong?
P.S adding -d flag when running not helped.

Comment: Your Entrypoint just prints out a statement and then exists.

Probably you could start bash on itself by using /bin/bash as the Entrypoint?

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 8):

Once the ENTRYPOINT completes (in any form), the container exits.

Once the container exits, you can't `docker exec` into it.

If you want to get a shell on the image you just built to poke around in it, you can

```
sudo docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh starter
```

To make this slightly easier to run, you might change ENTRYPOINT to CMD in your Dockerfile.  (Docker will run the ENTRYPOINT passing the CMD as command-line arguments; or if there is no entrypoint just run the CMD.)

```
...
RUN chmod +x ./app.sh
CMD ["./app.sh"]
```

Having done that, you can more easily override the command

```
sudo docker run --rm -it starter /bin/sh
```

Comment: but how my CMD section will look like?

Comment: and I need to go a docker container via exec -it and no other way.

Comment: and why do you run --rm it removes the container

Comment: Yes, that's right; I prefer to not leak dozens of finished temporary containers into the `docker ps` output.

Comment: So using --rm means that container is killed in the end?

Answer (score 3):

You can try
`docker start container_id` and then `docker exec -ti container_id bash` for a stopped container.

Answer (score 1):

I tried these two commands and it works:

```
sudo docker start <container_id>
docker exec -it <containerName> /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute the container, because your `ENTRYPOINT` script has been finished, and the container stopped. Try this:

1. Remove the `ENTRYPOINT` from your Dockerfile
2. Rebuild the image
3. run it with `sudo docker run -it -v mounted-directory:/usr/src/app/mounted-directory -p 80:80 starter sh`

The key is the `i` flag and the `sh` at the end of the command.

Comment: I need ENTRYPOINT because it runs entry.sh script. And even if I do as you said trying again to run exec -it command on container reproduces the error:(

Comment: Your entry script is executed, but stops the container, since it stops cleanly. You do need to start a process, which runs forever. Like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419500/how-do-you-start-a-docker-ubuntu-container-into-bash

Comment: To run forever I just to nee to add -d flag when running container. But that does not help.

Comment: @AntonyLapitskiy with -d flag it runs as daemon (in the background) but it still stop when script ends, which is his main problem here as I mentioned in my first sentece in the answer. If you need the `ENTRYPOINT` script, than you need such a script which does not exists. Eg a phyton http server.

Comment: So could you write to me some working case if you know how to do it please. And one moment is about that when i deleting ENTRYPOINT from docker file i can go to a container without any problem.

Comment: I am afraid that is an entirely new problem and question. Please, see [how to write good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)